# How do I find the infinite sum? $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\,\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^{1/2^k}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This question is from 'Differential Calculus' by 'Joseph Edwards', from chapter Differentiation. But how will I use the standard form of differentiation to solve such infinite sums?

Comment: Does it converge for any $x \ge 0$?

Comment: A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Which page it is on ?

Comment: Page 40, Question number 85

Comment: It should be noted that, here |x| < 1

Comment: Which book ? Elementary Treatise on Differential Calculus ?

Comment: Differential Calculus for Beginners by Joseph Edwards

Comment: I cant find it on page 40. Maybe a different edition.

Comment: $x^{\frac{1}{k}}\to 1 $ as $k\to \infty$ so comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{k}$ gives that the series diverges.

Comment: yes, I was mistakenly read. I'm really sorry!

Comment: Please do the needful

Comment: Don't just apologize in the comments, edit the question to fix it

Comment: @jjagmath I agree, someone should edit this question.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$S_n=(1+x^{\frac{1}{2}})(1+x^{\frac{1}{4}})\cdots(1+x^{\frac{1}{2^n}})$$

Then $$\ln S_n=\ln (1+x^{\frac{1}{2}})+\cdots +
\ln (1+x^{\frac{1}{2^n}})$$

and differentiating we get

$$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{2^k}}}{1+x^{\frac{1}{2^k}}}$$

On the other hand,
$$S_n=\frac{1-x}{1-x^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}$$

And taking the logarithmic derivative, which is what that chapter is all about

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln S_n= \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{2^n} \frac{1}{(x^{\frac{1}{2^n}}-1)x^{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}}$$

Now $$2^n(x^{\frac{1}{2^n}}-1)\to \ln x$$

and
$$x^{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}\to x$$

So we have derived that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{2^k}}}{1+x^{\frac{1}{2^k}}}=
\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\ln x}$$

For our desired series,

$$\sum\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{1}{1+x^{\frac{1}{2^k}}}
=\sum\frac{1}{2^k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{2^k}}}{1+x^{\frac{1}{2^k}}}$$

and the final closed form is

$$1-\frac{x}{x-1}+\frac{1}{\ln x}.$$

Comment: @Henry Good point, its a singular value of the expression.

Comment: So the original sum should be more like $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-k}}{1+x^{2^{-k}}} \, ?$$

Comment: @Diger Yes - see Q85 of https://archive.org/details/differentialcal03edwagoog/page/n68/mode/2up

Comment: @Henry Yes I made a stupid mistake. But I have edited my answer, I have the right method now. Hopefully there are no sign errors.

Comment: Just a little detail. The exercise from the book begin the series from $k=0$.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks, so the constant in the final form should be $2$. Dont know if I am going to edit. OP needs to get his act together. But its an interesting question.

Comment: Not exactly, you'll need to add the first term of the series  ($1/(1+x)$). Not important. I agree with you: OP should show more interest in his own question. I also agree it's an interesting exercise.

Comment: Looks good and correct now (+1)  You could write it as $\dfrac1{\ln(x)}- \dfrac{1}{x-1}$, while it is  $\frac12$ when $x=1$

Comment: @jjagmath Well I think I am solving the problem with $k=1$ :-)